# HTML Element Array, name="something[]" or name="something"?

Tags: php, html

I saw something on this site:

**Handling array of HTML Form Elements in JavaScript and PHP**
http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=343

It said to put the array in the `name` property and how to get the input collection's value. For example, `name="education[]"`

But as I know, an HTML input element is array-ready by `name`.
On the client-side (`GetElementsByName`) or server-side (`$_POST` in PHP or `Request.Form` in ASP.NET).

For example: `name="education"`, so what is the different with or
without the `[]`?

Comment: with education[], you can have input fields with names something like education[subject][1] and education[subject][2] as get the corresponding associative array on the server side (in php $_POST['education'])

Comment: The link is broken: *“Not Found. The requested URL / was not found on this server.”*

Answer (score 63, accepted):

PHP uses the square bracket syntax to convert form inputs into an array, so when you use `name="education[]"` you will get an array when you do this:

```
$educationValues = $_POST['education']; // Returns an array
print_r($educationValues); // Shows you all the values in the array
```

So for example:

```
<p><label>Please enter your most recent education<br>
    <input type="text" name="education[]">
</p>
<p><label>Please enter any previous education<br>
    <input type="text" name="education[]">
</p>
<p><label>Please enter any previous education<br>
    <input type="text" name="education[]">
</p>
```

Will give you all entered values inside of the `$_POST['education']` array.

In JavaScript, it is more efficient to get the element by id...

```
document.getElementById("education1");
```

The id doesn't have to match the name:

```
<p><label>Please enter your most recent education<br>
   <input type="text" name="education[]" id="education1">
</p>
```

Comment: But in my code, when I access array values through jquery, it gets an additional empty input value as well. Assume if I have entered 2 values, but it comes with 3 values which is one value as an empty string.

Comment: Make sure that if you are generating elements in a loop, that you are not generating duplicated `id` attributes in the same HTML document -- duplicate `id` values will cause an HTML document to be invalid.

Answer (score 18):

It's different.

If you post this form:

```
<input type="text" name="education[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="education[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="education[]" value="3">
```

you will get an array in PHP. In this example you will get `$_POST['education'] = [1, 2, 3]`.

If you post this form without `[]`,

```
<input type="text" name="education" value="1">
<input type="text" name="education" value="2">
<input type="text" name="education" value="3">
```

you will get the last value. Here you will get `$_POST['education'] = 3`.

Answer (score 17):

If you have checkboxes, you can pass an array of checked values.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="orange"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apple"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="banana"/>
```

Also multiple select dropdowns

```
<select name="fruits[]" multiple>
    <option>apple</option>
    <option>orange</option>
    <option>pear</option>
</select>
```