# PHP using input with the type checkbox, but is not required

Tags: php, forms, input, checkbox

I'm a beginner with PHP and I'm building a sign-up form. Now I'm using also the type="checkbox" because I want to now with the form wich day people are visiting in a week.

When I'm processing the form everything goes well if somebody check one of the boxes, but not when people don't check one of the checkboxes, then I'll get a PHP Implode error.

```
<li><input class="bso" type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="monday"/> monday</li>
<li><input class="bso" type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="tuesday"/> tuesday</li>
<li><input class="bso" type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="wednesday"/> wednesday</li>
<li><input class="bso" type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="thursday"/> thursday</li>
<li><input class="bso" type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="friday"/> friday</li>
```

So what I need to know is, what kind of php code do I need to succesfully process my PHP code without getting a warning when somebody doesn't check one of the boxes, because sometimes the people that are gone use the form don't want to visit.

THNX!

Comment: there is already a question like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something

i guess in order to avoid the error u need to check if it is empty first

if (!empty($_POST['day'])) { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that you need to check the existence of values for `day` in the POST and verify the value for `day` is indeed an array before trying to do `implode()` on that array.

```
$day_string = '';
if(!empty($_POST['day']) && is_array($_POST['day'])) {
    $day_string = implode(',', $day);
} else {
    // you didn't get at least one day checked, so issue error in this code block
}
```

If this same code is run for both GET and POST, then you might need to check that this is a POST (as `else if` or before even entering this block of code) such that you don;t get an error shown for GET requests.

As a matter of practice you should ALWAYS check for the existence of and validate expected format/values of any user-provided input before working with it in your code.  Get yourself familiar with `isset()`, `empty()`, `filter_var()`, `is_array()` and similar functions.

Comment: Thnx for your quick answer! I'm doing some experiences with my php code and now I'm stuck. What I'm trying is that I'm writing a code that you must check one of the boxes and if you don't you get a echo that's saying "you haven't checked one of the boxes" but I'm failing hard with writing the code!

Comment: @user2032585 Well typically, I always approach such validation issues on two fronts.  First, I put javascript validation on the page itself, such that ideally the form wouldn't even be posted.  Then I put validation on the server-side as well (as you can't trust client behavior).  In your case, you can simply add an `else` condition to the conditional I placed earlier.  I have updated my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: Your script was really helpful, thnx again!! But since a month it stopped working, while I didn't chance a thing. The problem is now that I'm not receiving the results from the checkboxes anymore except "Array", how is that possible?

Comment: @user2032585 I am not sure I am following your problem. If you have not changed your HTML and not changed your PHP, I see no reason why your behavior would change. I don't know what you mean by `I'm not receiving the results from the checkboxes anymore except "Array"`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you well, you want to get some form of statistics about when do your visitors hit your website. Isn't it easier if you slide a hidden input like this?:

```
<input type="hidden" name="day" value="<?php print strtolower(date("l")); ?>">
```

That way, you would get what you want without your users having to click anything. On monday, this would look like `<input type="hidden" name="day" value="monday">` and so on.

Hope that helps :P