# laravel how to validatate dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I have a page that has a drop down list to select `an action`. this select has a name `action_id`. The use can have many actions. So, I added a link, when the user clicks it, I generate a new select using javascript and jquery and then add this new select to the DOM. this new select also has a name `action_id`.

Finally I would have many select(s) with the name `action_id`

I created this jsfiddle for you to show you what I mean

http://jsfiddle.net/FMQtL/

My question is how to validate each `action_id` select in my controller when I submit the form?

Many thanks

#### Update 1

Usually, I just do this in the controller:

```
Input::get('action_id');
```

but this time I have many `action_id`(s)

Comment: Change action_id by action_id[] and you should get an array of action_id's

Comment: @Babblo do you mean `Input::get('action_id[]')` ?

Comment: You could likely then just still use `Input::get('action_id')` and it would return an array instead of a single value. Probably quicker to just test it.

Comment: He means where you assign the name in your select.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent Try `Input::get('action_id[]')` as @Babblo wrote.

Comment: @OscarJara yes I am trying it

Comment: @OscarJara I tried this `echo Input::get('action_id[]');` in the controller and I got nothing, nothing has been printed though I changed the name of the select(s) from `action_id` to `action_id[]`

Comment: @Babblo check my last comment please

Comment: and when I tried `dd(Input::get('action_id[]'));` I got `NULL`

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent I don't use lavarel, but after a quick search I think you need something like this: `$actions = Input::get('action_id'); foreach($actions as $action) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$actions = Input::get('action_id');
```

Where actions should ba an array. From this you can pretty much do whatever you want. The easy way is to do a foreach.

```
foreach($actions as $action) {
//validate
}
```