# Get value of form control with array name

Tags: php

I have a named form control:

```
<input class="form-control" name="user['first_name']" value="">
```

How can I get its value after it has been submitted via POST?

I tried these and none of them seems to work:

```
echo $_REQUEST['user']->fname;
echo $_POST['user[fname]'];
echo $_POST['user']['fname'];
```

Comment: You have a typo... Debug your own code yourself using `var_dump($variable)`

Comment: `fname` or `first_name`?

Comment: `$_POST["user"]["'first_name'"]` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Element Array, name="something\[\]" or name="something"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, get all value using foreach loop

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //do something
    echo $key . ' has the value of ' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's useless because your `user['first_name']` will never change, then Mohammad has the good answer, it's `$_POST['user']["'first_name'"]`, but if you want your user['first_name'] to change always, change it to put your php inside like this :

```
<?php echo "<input class='form-control' name='".$user['first_name']."' value=''>" ?>
```