# Increment name attribute when adding new form inputs fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a form there is an add button which adds form inputs. At the new form inputs I tried to increment the attribute `name` e.g `name="description-1"`,  `name="description-2"` etc. However, all the new inputs have the same  `name="description-1"`. What I miss?

```js
var dataList = $('.products');
var jsonOptions = [{
  "product": "11111",
  "description": "description 1"
}, {
  "product": "22222",
  "description": "description 2"
}, {
  "product": "33333",
  "description": "description 3"
}];

jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {

  var option = '<option value="' + item.product + '">' + item.description + '</option>';

  dataList.append(option);
});

$(function() {
  $('body').on('input', '.product,.products', function() {

    var i = this.value;
    var description = "";
    var productsInBox = 0;

    jsonOptions.forEach(function(a) {
      if (a.product == i) {
        description = a.description;
      }
    });
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.description').val(description);


  });
});

counter = 0;

$('#form1').on('click', '.addButtonDED', function() {
    counter++;
    var $template = $('.form-group:last').clone(true, true).find('input').val('').end()
      .find('.addButtonDED').removeClass('addButtonDED').addClass('removeButtonDED').end()
      .find('[name="description-0"]').attr('name', 'description-' + counter).end()
      .find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus').end();
    $template.insertAfter('.form-group:last');
  })

  // Remove button click handler
  .on('click', '.removeButtonDED', function() {
    counter--;
    var $row = $(this).closest('.form-group');
    $row.remove();
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <fieldset>


    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" list="products" class="form-control product" name="product" />
        <datalist id="products" class="products"></datalist>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input id="" type="text" class="form-control description" name="description-0" />
      </div>



      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButtonDED"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 ">
      <button type="submit" name="formAction" value="next" class="btn btn-primary">sUBMIT</button>

    </div>



  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accesing always to `'[name="description-0"]'` so when you change their name to `description-1`, that selector won't select them anymore.

You should select them with this selector `'[name^="description-"]'`.

The `^=` operator means to select every element that starts with the stated value, so it will select all your `description-0`, `description-1` and `description-whatever`.

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_beginning_value.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by simple change `[name="description-0"]` to  `[name="description-'+ (counter-1) +'"]`

The problem is that you `close` the previous object, and then the `decription-0` will not be 0 anymore after the first object.

```js
var dataList = $('.products');
var jsonOptions = [{
  "product": "11111",
  "description": "description 1"
}, {
  "product": "22222",
  "description": "description 2"
}, {
  "product": "33333",
  "description": "description 3"
}];

jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {

  var option = '<option value="' + item.product + '">' + item.description + '</option>';

  dataList.append(option);
});

$(function() {
  $('body').on('input', '.product,.products', function() {

    var i = this.value;
    var description = "";
    var productsInBox = 0;

    jsonOptions.forEach(function(a) {
      if (a.product == i) {
        description = a.description;
      }
    });
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.description').val(description);


  });
});

counter = 0;

$('#form1').on('click', '.addButtonDED', function() {
    counter++;
    var $template = $('.form-group:last').clone(true, true).find('input').val('').end()
      .find('.addButtonDED').removeClass('addButtonDED').addClass('removeButtonDED').end()
      .find('[name="description-'+ (counter-1) +'"]').attr('name', 'description-' + counter).end()
      .find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus').end();
    $template.insertAfter('.form-group:last');
  })

  // Remove button click handler
  .on('click', '.removeButtonDED', function() {
    counter--;
    var $row = $(this).closest('.form-group');
    $row.remove();
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <fieldset>


    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" list="products" class="form-control product" name="product" />
        <datalist id="products" class="products"></datalist>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input id="" type="text" class="form-control description" name="description-0" />
      </div>



      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButtonDED"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 ">
      <button type="submit" name="formAction" value="next" class="btn btn-primary">sUBMIT</button>

    </div>



  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual issue is `var $template = $('.form-group:last').clone(true, true)` , specifically the `:last` bit which means that its going to grab the one on the bottom of the group therefore `.find('[name="description-0"]')` only matches the first time. After that, the element would have `name="description-1"` and that call wont find it.

Instead, always grab the first element:

`var $template = $('.form-group').eq(0).clone(true, true)`

#### [Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/17/)

## However,

**Why are you incrementing your name attributes at all?**

Are you sending this data to some server side processing like `php`? if so, why not use the array syntax like:

```
    <input id="" type="text" class="form-control description" name="description[]" />
```

See [HTML Element Array, name="something[]" or name="something"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something)

Comment: I am actually read these values from a `servlet`. At first I had as you wrote `name="description[]"` but I couldn't read the values.. that's why I am incrementing the name attributes.

Comment: Your solution works, but when I fill the 1st row and then I press the add button, then the new line is the already filled with the data of the 1st line. Anyway, thx for info and that's why +1 voted you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find('.description').attr('name', 'description-' + counter).end()`

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gj2w1xvx/1/)

```
$('#form1').on('click', '.addButtonDED', function() {
  counter++;

  var $template = $('.form-group:last').clone(true, true).find('input').val('').end()
    .find('.addButtonDED').removeClass('addButtonDED').addClass('removeButtonDED').end()
    .find('.description').attr('name', 'description-' + counter).end()
    .find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus').end();
  $template.insertAfter('.form-group:last');
  alert(counter)
})
```