# send data from form with <li> attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My data in my form will be inserted by javascript. These are li attributes. I want to send the data in these li attributes to an other php page. But that's not possible?

```js
    function addProduct() {
            //var productid = document.getElementById('product').value;
            var product = products[type];
            //this is just a product placeholder
            //you should insert an item with the selected product info
            //replace productId, productName, price and url with your real product info
            var productAdded = $('<li class="product" name="product' + i + '">' +
                '<div class="product-image">' +
                '<a href="image">' +
                '<img src="images/' + product + '.jpg" alt="placeholder"></a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="product-details">' +
                '<a style="color: black;">' + product + '</a>' +
                '<span class="price">€ ' + price + '</span><br>' +
                '<div class="quantity">' +
                '<label>Aantal: ' + qty + '</label> <div class="actions">' +
                ' <a href="#0" class="delete-item" >Delete</a></div></div></div></li>');
    
            cartList.prepend(productAdded);
            
        }
```

```html
    <div class="cd-cart">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <header>
                    <h2>Winkelkar</h2>
                    <span class="undo">Verwijder product. <a href="#0">Ongedaan maken</a></span>
                </header>
    
                <div class="body">
                    <form id="formtosubmit" class="form-style-12" action="checkout.php" method="post">
                        <ul name="products">
                        <!-- products added to the cart will be inserted here using JavaScript -->
                        </ul>
                    </form>
                </div>
    
                <footer>
                    <a id="checkoutbtn" class="checkout btn" onclick="document.getElementById('formtosubmit').submit()"><em>Ga verder: €<span>0</span></em></a>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `<input type='hidden'/>` element in between those `<li>` tags and write each product ID or product name to the value of that `<input>` tag. This way when you submit your form, those values will be captured.

EX:

```
function addProduct() {
        var productid = document.getElementById('product').value;
        var product = products[type];
        //this is just a product placeholder
        //you should insert an item with the selected product info
        //replace productId, productName, price and url with your real product info
        var productAdded = $('<li class="product" name="product' + i + '">' +
            '<div class="product-image">' +
            '<a href="image">' +
            '<img src="images/' + product + '.jpg" alt="placeholder"></a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="product-details">' +
            '<a style="color: black;">' + product + '</a>' +
            '<span class="price">€ ' + price + '</span><br>' +
            '<div class="quantity">' +
            '<input type="hidden" value="'+productid+'" readonly name='productid[]'>' +
            '<label>Aantal: ' + qty + '</label> <div class="actions">' +
            ' <a href="#0" class="delete-item" >Delete</a></div></div></div></li>');

        cartList.prepend(productAdded);

    }
```

Now you may have noticed what is that `name='productid[]'` in input tag? That means create an array of every input value particular to that element. More information can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4689190/1173209).

Another approach would be saving your selected product IDs into a cookie/session variable. Then your server side can access that information and process the cart accordingly. If you were to delete a product from the cart then make sure you update your session/cookie value as well.