# how to get the submit button value which is in while loop using post method

Tags: php, mysql

1. Input field inside a while condition i'm displaying the tab in which tab values are fetched from table red_digid_info

   ```
   <form method="POST" action="" id="form_isp_status" onsubmit="submit_isp_status('form_isp_status');"">
                               <div class="row">
                               <label for="fromdate" class="col-sm-1 control-label">&nbsp;&nbsp;FROM DATE </label>
                               <label for="todate" class="col-sm-1 control-label" style="margin-left: 4cm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;TO DATE </label>
                               </div>
                               <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-sm-1">
                               <div class="input-group">
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fromdatepicker" name="fromdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"  style="width:200px;height:33px;"> 
                                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></i></span>
                               </div>
                               </div> 
                               <div class="col-sm-1" style="margin-left:4cm">
                               <div class="input-group">
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todatepicker" name="todate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"  style="width:200px;height:33px;"> 
                                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></i></span>
                               </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
                                       <input type="submit" value="ISP Status" class='btn btn-purple btn-rounded w-md  m-b-5' name="isp_button">
                                       <input type="hidden" value="1" name="pointer">
                                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-rounded w-md  m-b-5" onclick="resetforms('form_isp_status')">Reset</button>
                               </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="row">
                               <label for="isp" class="col-sm-1 control-label">&nbsp;&nbsp;SELECT ISP</label>
                               </div><div class="row">
       <div class="tab">
           <?php 
               $isp_tab = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(`isp`) FROM `red_dgid_info`");
               while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($isp_tab)) {
                   $isp_value = $result[0];
                   echo '<input class="tablinks ion-social-rss" type="submit" name="isp_value[]" value="'.$isp_value.'">';
                   //echo '<input type="hidden" name="isp_hidden_value[]" value="'.$isp_value.'">';
               } 
           ?>
       </div>
   </div></form>
   ```
2. if i click any one value of a tab i ve to display the tab content so i need the value of submit button in php post method

   ```
   if($_REQUEST['pointer'] ==1)
   {   
   var_dump($_POST);                   
   //-------status criteria given---------------------// 

       //-----------isp tab submiited--------------// 
       if(isset($_POST['isp_value'])) 
       {
               print_r($_POST['isp_value']);
               $isp=$_POST['isp_value'];

       }
       //------------------end----------------------//

       //----------hidden value array--------------//
       /*$data = $_POST['isp_hidden_value'];
       foreach($data as $isp)
       {
           echo "isp_hidden =".$isp;
       }
       //---------------another way----------------//
       $isp_hidden = $_POST['isp_hidden_value'][$isp];*/
       //--------------end------------------------//

   $date= date("Y-m-d");;
   $fromdatepicker =$_POST['fromdate'];
   $todatepicker =$_POST['todate'];
   exit;
   }
   ```

if(isset($_POST['isp_value'])) //this if condition fails isp_value is not set don't know the reason and solution for it

3. submit function

   ```
   function submit_isp_status(formId) { 
   if($("#"+formId).valid() == true) {
      $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'webxstatus.php', //same page
           data: $("#"+formId).serialize(), 
           success: function(data) {
               ..........
                                   }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

I'm stuck with this for past 2 days anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: it's because of your `name`. You have one name used in your loop so what will happen there is that as you've described only the latest value will be fetched. To fix this you try changing your name into an array something like this `name="hidden_value[]"` refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something)

Comment: In echo i got like this isp_hidden =Array if i use the name as name="hidden_value[]" @hungrykoala

Comment: what does `submit_isp_status` do?

Comment: It just submit the form @Jelmergu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your input name to array like this `isp_value[]`  so only you can get the value which submit button you clicked  otherwise you will get last value only .

```
echo "<input class='tablinks ion-radio-waves' type='submit' name='isp_value[]' value='$isp_value'></input>"
```

PHP :

`print_r($_POST['isp_value']);`

And also minor single quotes problem in your isp_hidden_value

`echo '<input type="hidden" name="isp_hidden_value[]" value="'.$isp_value.'">';`

note:

if you need currently clicked submit button value means . don't use hidden field it will collect all values . just insert the value in submit button it will collect only curently clicked element value only as a array

Try this example :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['xyz']))
{

    print_r($_POST);
}
?>

 <form action="" method="post">

   <input type="submit" name="xyz[]" value="1" >
   <input type="submit" name="xyz[]" value="2" >

  </form>
```

Comment: In echo i didn't get any value isp = ' ' @JYoThI

Comment: print_r($_POST['isp_value']); @puvi

Comment: and also minor single quotes problem in your isp_hidden_value  echo '<input type="hidden" name="isp_hidden_value[]" value="'.$isp_value.'">';

Comment: if you need currently clicked submit button value means . don't use hidden field it will collect all values . just insert the value in submit button it will collect only curently clicked element value only as array  @puvi

Comment: In print_r also i didn't get any value for isp_value @JYoThl

Comment: what you  get when you print ? is there any empty array ? @puvi

Comment: no I got nothing I think isp_value is not set dont know what's happening @JYoThl

Comment: you need to change your name attribute  to array like this name='isp_value[]' @puvi

Comment: i forget to update that in my code i ve changed it to isp_value[] and tried @JYoThl

Comment: you can't echo the array use print_r($isp); @puvi

Comment: first of all you not setting value propel to the form .  $isp_value = $result[0]; is not valid try this one  $isp_value = $result[DISTINCT(`isp`)]; @puvi

Comment: yes i ve tried print_r($isp); but i get the submittted value through javascript alert but not in php  <script type="text/javascript">
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
alert(this.value);

});
</script> @JYoThl

Comment: by using $result[isp]; i got the same result by using $result[[DISTINCT(isp)] I dont even get the tab values @JYoThl Thank you so much for your kind replies :)

Comment: Bit of a long shot but will try anyway, this answered a problem I was having with this but was wondering how I can have the array value and have a submit face value just for appearence to the customer. As the button value just says the value but I want it to say "Add"

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php $isp_tab=mysql_query("select distinct(isp) from red_dgid_info");
            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($isp_tab))
                {
echo'<form method="POST" action="" id="form_isp_status" onsubmit="submit_isp_status('form_isp_status');">';
            $isp_value =$result[0];
            echo "<input class='tablinks ion-radio-waves' type='submit' name='isp_value' value='$isp_value'></input>";
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="isp_hidden_value" value='$isp_value'>';
echo'</form>';
                }?>
```

put form inside while loop

Comment: Why put a form inside while loop?? If a table has 1000 records then it will generate 1000 form ... Is it valid?? and how to fetch data for individual form???

Comment: its valid and which submit button you click only that form data will be send

Comment: Are you talking about something like that http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8z15-gm94

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144985/discussion-between-nidhi-and-nishit-manjarawala).

Comment: I also have other fields like date if i use the form inside a while loop all the other fields are also repeated @NishitManjarawala

Comment: yes it repeated but when you use form in loop and u click on submit only that form data will be submit

Comment: wait i explain you here

Comment: example.
while(true){
<form>
<input type="text" name="test"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
}
for example in upon example if you got two form like below
<form>
<input type="text" name="test"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />//if you click on this submit then it will send all data of this form only it means this form text box and submit value only
</form>

<form>
<input type="text" name="test"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

Answer (score 0):

```
 while($result=mysql_fetch_array($isp_tab))
            {
        $isp_value =$result[0];
        echo "<input class='tablinks ion-radio-waves' type='submit' name='isp_value' value='$isp_value'></input>";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="isp_hidden_value[]" value='$isp_value'>';
            }?>


$data =$_POST['isp_hidden_value'];
    foreach($data as $isp)
    {
        echo "isp_hidden"=$isp;
    }
```

Use input field 'isp_hidden_value' as array  and fetch values using foreach

Comment: by using for each i got all the values of a row but i only need a submmited tab value @sreeja seguro

Comment: echo "<input class='tablinks ion-radio-waves' type='submit' name='isp_value[]' value='".$isp_value."'></input>";  use submit input text as array and get submitted tab value by $ispvalue=$_POST['isp_value'];
 $isp=$_POST['isp_value'][0];

Comment: I have changed the name as name='isp_value[]' then how to get the submitted tab value can u explain me clearly @sreeja seguro

Comment: when we submit tab value evenif it is array it pass only current tab value .ie $_POST['isp_value']  is an array containing only one value ie  current tab value we get that value by '$_POST['isp_value'][0] 'this.

Comment: I have tried $_POST['isp_value'][0] still didn't get any value I think my isp_value is not set thats why i didn't get any submitted tab value @sreeja seguro

Comment: first you try to set static value for isp_value inside the loop  and check value for $_POST['isp_value'][0]

Comment: how to set the static value @sreeja seguro

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes in your code, and after that i hope it will work perfectly:

1. Change hidden field

from:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="isp_hidden_value" value="$isp_value">';
```

to:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='isp_hidden_value[$isp_value]' value='" . $isp_value . "'>";
```

2. In the post method change value assignment of hidden field

from:

`$isp_hidden = $_POST['isp_hidden_value'];`

to:

```
$isp_hidden = $_POST['isp_hidden_value'][$isp];
```

Rest should work fine.

Logic behind this change is to use array when using same name for multiple input types. Here you are using a flat variable which will hold only one value, which will get assigned at the end. If you use array it will hold multiple values and allows you to get your desired result.

Comment: my name='isp_value[]' is not set.. :( Is there any solution for it @Pranit Jha

Comment: To hold values of all the fields generated from PHP loop we need to create array of it. So, here you need to define name as array by using "[]" after name.

Comment: I have created the array name, but in post method if(isset($_POST['isp_value'])) this condition fails @Pranit Jha

Comment: Share your current code, so that i can figure out the actual issue.

Comment: It is working. I used your code, and it is resulting the array.

Comment: Code:
<form method="POST" action="" id="form_isp_status" onsubmit="submit_isp_status('form_isp_status');"> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="tab">
<?php
$isp_tab = array(
array("0" => "A"), array("0" => "B"), array("0" => "C")
);
foreach ($isp_tab as $result) {
$isp_value = $result[0];
        echo "<input class='tablinks ion-radio-waves' type='submit' name='isp_value[]' value='$isp_value'></input>";        
      }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['isp_value']) && !empty($_POST['isp_value'])) {
  $isp = $_POST['isp_value'];
  print_r($isp);
}

Comment: Only part i have changed is, i'm using static array instead of db result.

Comment: if i use isp_value as select option and submit it using another button it works and shows the result, but if i use 'isp_value' as a tab and submit it 'isp_value' is not set @Pranit Jha

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a hidden field for this. A button with a name should send it's value.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="tab">
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="test1">
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="test2">
    </div>
</div> </form>
```

Will tell me that `$_POST['button']` is either `test1` or `test2`

Which means that the following should work

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="form_isp_status" onsubmit="submit_isp_status('form_isp_status');"">
<div class="row">
    <div class="tab">
        <?php $isp_tab=mysql_query("select distinct(isp) from red_dgid_info");
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($isp_tab))
        {
            $isp_value =$result[0];
            echo "<input class='tablinks ion-radio-waves' type='submit' name='isp_value' value='$isp_value'>";
            // note: input is a empty tag, meaning that it is not to be closed using </input> but by using />, which
            // is only relevant for XHTML
            }?>
    </div>
</div> </form>
```

Edit:
On the server side the only thing you have to do is use the value of `$_POST['isp_value']`.

```
var_dump($_POST); // only to check the POST variable during debugging

if (isset($_POST['isp_value'])) { // Possibly not needed if there are no other submit buttons in the from, but good practice to check if something exists
    // do something using $_POST['isp_value']
}
```

As a sidenote: mysql_* has been deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and been removed in PHP 7.0. It is recommended to either use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead

Comment: k i removed the hidden field and </input> then what i have to do to get the submitted tab value @Jelmergu

Comment: Edited my answer. Note that the var_dump is only there to see what the post output is. If it is correct the value of isp_value should be the same value as the button you clicked on

Comment: array(4) { ["fromdate"]=> string(0) "" ["todate"]=> string(0) "" ["pointer"]=> string(1) "1" ["isp_hidden_value"]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(7) "comcast" [1]=> string(5) "yahoo" [2]=> string(5) "gmail" [3]=> string(10) "roadrunner" [4]=> string(7) "verizon" [5]=> string(3) "att" [6]=> string(7) "hotmail" [7]=> string(3) "aol" [8]=> string(4) "juno" } }  expect name='isp_value[]' other string values are displayed through var_dump($_POST) @Jelmergu