# Submit value inside while loop condition is not set in post value of PHP

Tags: php

1. I need the post value of 'isp_value'

   ```
   while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($isp_tab)) 
    {
       $isp_value = $result[0];
       echo '<input class="tablinks ion-social-rss" type="submit" name="isp_value[]" value="'.$isp_value.'">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="isp_hidden_value[]" value="'.$isp_value.'">';

    }
   ```
2. Im getting hidden value of isp_hidden_value[] but not the value of isp_value[]

   ```
   $data = $_POST['isp_hidden_value'];
       foreach($data as $isp)
       {
           echo "isp_hidden =".$isp; //this echo works and show all the values in a row
       }
   if(isset($_POST['isp_value'])) //if condition fails isp_value is not set(!isset)
       {
               //$isp = $_POST['isp_value'];
               //echo 'isp  = '.$isp;
               print_r($_POST['isp_value']);

       }
   ```
3. I need the submitted one value from isp_value
4. By using `<?php var_dump($_POST);?>` all values in a row from name='hidden_value[]' are shown but not a single submitted value from name='isp_value[]'.

   ```
   ["isp_hidden_value"]=> array(9) { ["comcast"]=> string(7) "comcast" ["yahoo"]=> string(5) "yahoo" ["gmail"]=> string(5) "gmail" ["roadrunner"]=> string(10) "roadrunner" ["verizon"]=> string(7) "verizon" ["att"]=> string(3) "att" ["hotmail"]=> string(7) "hotmail" ["aol"]=> string(3) "aol" ["juno"]=> string(4) "juno" } }
   ```

Anyone help me solve this problem

Comment: `$isp` is an array, you can't echo it. Also, why you need array for button? simply use `name='isp_value'`. You will press only one button to submit the form

Comment: You have to change input type from button to some other type.

Comment: either print_r($_POST['isp_value']); also didn't work @Thamilan

Comment: i'm using input type="submit" @RanjeetSingh

Comment: You have already posted similar question. What is your exact need? Is the first comment not enough for you to proceed?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149391/how-to-get-the-submit-button-value-which-is-in-while-loop-using-post-method

Comment: I have posted the previous question for getting hidden fields and how to get the post values but now my problem is submit button is not set (!isset($_POST['isp_value']) condition is true now i need to solve this @Thamilan

Comment: how to set static value for isp_value inside the loop @Thamilan

Comment: Isn't it fine?  `echo '<input class="tablinks ion-social-rss" type="submit" name="isp_value" value="'.$isp_value.'">';`

Comment: that also not working is it possible to ve 2 submit buttons in a form does that cause any issues? @Thamilan

Comment: No, you can have

Comment: thanks for your replies @Thamilan

Comment: Does that work?

Comment: nope :( @Thamilan

Comment: if i use isp_value as select option and submit it using another button it works and shows the result, but if i use 'isp_value' as a tab and submit it 'isp_value' is not set @Thamilan

Comment: $isp_value also will be an array. Even if only one is submitted, you have defined it like isp_value[], so it will be an array. Use it like this - $data = $_POST['isp_hidden'];
    foreach($data as $isp)
    {
        echo "isp =".$isp; 
    }

Comment: now i need one submitted tab value refer my previous question. @T.Shah

Comment: It will give only one value - the one that is clicked.

Comment: yeah i tried that one @T.Shah but not working refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149391/how-to-get-the-submit-button-value-which-is-in-while-loop-using-post-method for full code