# PHP - HTML: Select attribute after $_POST is giving value 'Array'

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

Recently I got a problem with `$_POST` method. Here is select attribute in HTML that is giving informations by POST method.

```
<select name="date_year[]" required>
                    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="true">Choose year...</option>
                    <option value="07"> 2007</option>
                    <option value="08"> 2008</option>
                    <option value="09"> 2009</option>
                    <option value="10"> 2010</option>
                    <option value="11"> 2011</option>
                    <option value="12"> 2012</option>
                    <option value="13"> 2013</option>
                    <option value="14"> 2014</option>
                    <option value="15"> 2015</option>
                    <option value="16"> 2016</option>
                    <option value="17"> 2017</option>
                    <option value="18"> 2018</option>
                    <option value="19"> 2019</option>
                    <option value="20"> 2020</option>
                    </select>
```

after submiting form with this select tag, in PHP code I have something like this:

```
$month_date = $_POST['date_month'];
$year_date = $_POST['date_year'];

$final_date = $month_date . ' '. $year_date;
$esult = $connection->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if($connection->query("INSERT INTO thread VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$final_date', '$desc', '$thumbnail', '$gallery_img')")) {
    unset($_POST['upload']);
    header('Location: panel.php');
    $connection->close();
    exit();
}
```

Here just look for these `$_POST` things. I just gave the full code for the context. Here is my problem: after a successfull insert to my MySQL database, I got the value "Array Array". From curiosity I echo'ed that `$final_date` but still, it's just 'Array Array'. Why?

Comment: Have you used js to post that form?

Comment: because you defined your select as `name="date_year[]"`, so it's an array. Remove the `[]` from teh name ro do you need it to be an array?

Comment: Remove `[]` from `date_year[]` from `select`

Comment: Hey y'all, few minutes after the question I have saw that. The problem was that "[]" in the name of my select attribute. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize the query.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you are at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even **[escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)** is not safe! I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a function for](http://paragoncds.com/grumpy/pdoquery/#function) to make it extremely **easy**, very **clean**, and way more **secure** than using non-parameterized queries.

Comment: What does it mean? Should I use some HTML entities?

Comment: _“From curiosity I echo'ed that '$final_date' but still, it's just 'Array Array'. Why?”_ - because that happens when you `echo` an array ... To make debug outputs, you should use `var_dump`. Not only can that handle arrays as well, it also shows you the data type of what you output.

Comment: Hint: it seems that your question was caused by a simple typo - if so: consider deleting it.

Comment: _“What does it mean? Should I use some HTML entities?”_ - it means you should take the time to _read up_ on the issue, instead of coming with the knee-jerk reaction “what does it mean” as soon as someone mentions something that is new to you ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Element Array, name="something\[\]" or name="something"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<select name="date_year[]" required>
```

Into

```
<select name="date_year" required>
```

The brackets make the input field an array hence the `Array` in your query.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issue with your code:

```
<select name="date_year[]" required>
```

here there is no need to use name as an array. So change it to:

```
<select name="date_year" required>
```

and after concatenating:

```
$final_date = $month_date . ' '. $year_date;
```

the format is `m-Y` which is not acceptable for date column. The date column format is 'Y-m-d'

Answer (score 1):

As you have mention `date_year[]` as array in `select` tag, It will be result as array

change your select tag to

```
<select name="date_year" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html select element was following

```
<select name="date_year[]" required>
```

So you should access it like this

```
$year_date = $_POST['date_year'][0];
```

Not Like

```
$year_date = $_POST['date_year'];
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
<select name="date_year[]" required>
```

to this

```
<select name="date_year" required>
```

it will solve your problem.