# How to properly setup an array inside an input HTML attribute?

Tags: php, arrays, post, input, attributes

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something) I have created this html inside a form:

```
...
<input type="text" name="setValues[cardExpiration]" id="card_expiry" class="input-small" value="1222">
<input type="text" name="setValues[ipAddress]" id="ip" value="24.37.246.194">
...
```

After the form is submitted, inside the `$_POST` array I see this multi dimensional array as expected:
[image]

When I try to retrieve the value, something is happening:

```
$email = (isset($_POST["setValues"])?$_POST["setValues"]["email"]:FALSE);//Gives NULL

$email = (isset($_POST["setValues"])?$_POST["setValues"]["'email'"]:FALSE);//Gives the email filled in the form.
```

The point here is the **'** key **'** single quotes in the array key. It is being part of the key.

This is why `$_POST["setValues"]["'email'"]` works and `$_POST["setValues"]["email"]` don't.

So what should I do to get the array without quotes inside the key? How to properly setup it inside the input attribute?

This is the var_dump():

```
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

[image]

Comment: `$_POST["setValues"]["'email'"]` does not work, and `$_POST["setValues"]["email"]` does, as expected - see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the expected behavior with the following:

```
<form method='POST'>
<input type="text" name="setValues[cardExpiration]" id="card_expiry" class="input-small" value="1222">
<input type="text" name="setValues[ipAddress]" id="ip" value="24.37.246.194">
<input type="email" name="setValues[email]" id="email" value="test@testmail.com">
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

/* show $_POST array */
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

$email = (isset($_POST["setValues"])?$_POST["setValues"]["email"]:FALSE);
echo $email; /* output: test@testmail.com */

$email = (isset($_POST["setValues"])?$_POST["setValues"]["'email'"]:FALSE);
echo $email; /* output: Notice: Undefined index: 'email' */
}
?>
```

Comment: I just used the var_dump. As you can see, the keys are comming with quotes.