# Loop through POST array with PHP

Tags: php

I have a form on my website. When I submit it to my PHP script I use `var_dump($_POST);` to show all the form data that has been submitted. The array follows below.

I'd like to use PHP to run a *foreach* loop on the following array and group them by the index.

**Expected Output:**

```
1 - 111 - 1
2 - 222 - 2
3 - 333 - 3
```

So each row would have the relevant *name, source and level* based on the integer in the array element.

Can someone explain how this is done?

```
array(11) {
  ["source_name0_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["source_code0_id"]=>
  string(3) "111"
  ["source_level0_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["source_name1_id="]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["source_code1_id="]=>
  string(3) "222"
  ["source_level1_id="]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["source_name2_id="]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["source_code2_id="]=>
  string(3) "333"
  ["source_level2_id="]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "Submit"
}
```

***Thank you!***

Comment: Please show expected output ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet Good idea - have updated now :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Do you know how many you have? That is to ask, do you know the maximum of the number part?

Comment: @Chipster Unfortunately, I don't - the script allows the user to create multiple rows of data so it could be more than 2. Thanks for your answer. I may have a query about it.

Comment: Could the script keep track of the max and store it in a hidden input?

Comment: @Chipster Really good point. I'll have a think if I can do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$foreach($array /* or in the case $_POST? */ as $key => $value) {
    /// loop...
}
```

or just

```
$foreach($array as $value) {
    /// loop...
}
```

Edit: So, to get the output you're expecting, you do have another easy way, if you know the max ahead of time:

```
$for($i = 0; $i<$max /* if you have it */; $i++) {
  echo $_POST["source_name" . $i . "_id"] . " - " .
     $_POST["source_code" . $i . "_id"] . " - " .
  $_POST["source_level" . $i . "_id"] . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How do I determine `$max` value?

Comment: That's the tricky part. The easy way is to edit the script to track the max (or the number of rows submitted) and pass it to $_POST["maxRows"] or something like that.

Comment: Actually, better idea. You could consider using [name arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4689190/10957435) instead, and that'd make things a whole lot easier.

Comment: Why are you showing two empty `foreach(){}` constructs as `$foreach(){}`? Not sure this accomplishes the goal of the OP.

Comment: @Chipster - Great idea, will do! :-) Your edited script works great *however* when I run it, I just get 
1 - 111 - 1<br>
 -  - <br>
 -  - <br>

Comment: @michaelmcgurk That's strange. I realize I was missing a dot. Not sure that's the problem though. I just added it.

Comment: @jibsteroos The original post simply asked how to loop through all the element of the array, not necessarily make a given output as it now does.

Comment: @Chipster Thanks for all your efforts here. I think I just need to tweak this part and it'll be working: `for($i = 0; $i<$max; $i++) {`. This doesn't give me the expected output.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Hm. That's weird. Can you post the echo statement you're using?

Comment: My bad, I missed a bit. It works beautifully. Thank you, @Chipster!

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Yay! I'm glad.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$array = [
    "source_name0_id"=> "1",
    "source_code0_id"=> "111",
    "source_level0_id"=> "1",
    "source_name1_id="=> "2",
    "source_code1_id="=> "222",
    "source_level1_id="=> "2",
    "source_name2_id="=> "3",
    "source_code2_id="=> "333",
    "source_level2_id="=> "3",
    "submit"=> "Submit"
];

$output = [];

foreach($array as $key=>$val)
{
    $output[] = [$val, $key, $val];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```