# How to input array elements in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a `Post` model which has the following fields

```js
title: String,
image: String,
description: String,
tags: [
    { type: String }
],
```

For creating a post, I made a form that takes inputs for the above fields. For the first three inputs, I just gave `<input type="text">`. But I am not sure how I can get the input for `tags` which is an array of strings. I am expecting something like `tags = ["html","css","js"]` etc. What would be a good way to input these in a HTML form ?

Comment: If you know what all the strings could be, you can use a `<select>` input with the `multiple` attribute. If they can be anything, you'd need to create a custom input or just use a `type="text"` field and split by some delimiter.

Comment: if you adjust the input name to be an array (`<input type="text" name="tags[]" />`) and have multiple of these on the page, then `$_POST['tags']` should be an array. Depending on the _type_ of input you want, a multi-select as mentioned above might be best instead of this route. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something and https://mattstauffer.com/blog/a-little-trick-for-grouping-fields-in-an-html-form/ for more info.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones this works only if the OP is using PHP

Comment: @RobBailey Thanks for that idea, does the `select` input type make each selected inputs into an array by itself? Or do I need to add anything?